# Como pegar sempre o último vídeo de um canal do YouTube?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, vídeo

Tenho uma div `<div class="player"></div>` e dentro dela, quero que apareça sempre o último vídeo publicado em um canal.

Tenho essa estrutura em jQuery, porém não consigo fazer com que puxe apenas 1. Segue a estrutura:

```
$(function() {
    // Baixar URLs do feed do canal
    $.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Rodrigoaraujooficial/uploads?max-results=10&alt=json', function(result) {

        var entries = result.feed.entry;

        for(var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
            var url = entries[i].link[0].href;   

            // Transformar URL de vídeo em URL de embed
            // ANTES: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDqExWjK49Y&algumacoisaaqui
            // DEPOIS: http://www.youtube.com/embed/aDqExWjK49Y
            url = url.replace('/watch?v=', '/embed/');
            url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('&'));

            // Fazer append dos vídeos
            $('.player').append('<iframe width="480" height="270" src="' + url + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        }
    });
});
```

Como solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como os dados estão ordenados por data decrescente, o jeito mais fácil de pegar o último vídeo sem ter que mudar a estrutura do código é manipular o parametro `max-results` URL:
De:
`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Rodrigoaraujooficial/uploads?max-results=10&alt=json`
Para:
`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Rodrigoaraujooficial/uploads?max-results=1&alt=json`

Comment: Poxa cara, muito obrigado! Deu certo aqui!

Comment: De nada. Boa sorte com o código!

Comment: No caso para ser de outro canal eu tenho que alterar somente depois de users/ID_DO_CANAL ?

E no meu aqui deu um erro 410 (Gone).