# Mostrar somente o ultimo video do canal php

Tags: php

Tenho esse código, onde ao utilizar o comando `/lastvideo` ele mostra o ultimo vídeo do meu canal do youtube, porem ao tentar utilizar ele só mostra o link do youtube, não o vídeo

Codigo em Php

```
//CANAL
$canal = '1fHyqwbfORgIedvQ5fmWZQ';


//--------------------------------------------------------//


switch($mensagem){

    case "/lastvid":
        sendMessage($chatid, ($yt->lastVideo($canal)));
        break;
```

Chama essa função:

```
class YouTube {

    public $cid;


    public function lastVideo ($cid){

    $ulast = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=' .$cid. '&maxResults=1&order=date&type=video&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $glast = @file_get_contents($ulast);
    $dlast = json_decode($glast, true);

    $vid = @$dlast['items'][0]['id']['videoId'];
    $vname = @$dlast['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];

    //Condition

        $ret = "Assista meu ultimo video: " .$vname. "\n http://youtu.be" .$vid;

        return $ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: Você tem que pegar o id do último video, enviar pro banco de dados, atualizar a tabela, e então colocar no Youtube. Te aconselho os seguintes links : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617567/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-latest-uploaded-video-in-a-youtube-channel e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como pegar sempre o último vídeo de um canal do YouTube?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40324/como-pegar-sempre-o-%c3%baltimo-v%c3%addeo-de-um-canal-do-youtube)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se ajuda mas posso lhe dar o código em HTML e JavaScript.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="videos"></div>
```

**Javascript (com jQuery):**

```js
$(function() {
    // Baixar URLs do feed do canal
    $.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/**nome_do_utilizador**/uploads?max-results=10&alt=json', function(result) {

        var entries = result.feed.entry;

        for(var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
            var url = entries[i].link[0].href;   

            // Transformar URL de vídeo em URL de embed
            // ANTES: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDqExWjK49Y&algumacoisaaqui
            // DEPOIS: http://www.youtube.com/embed/aDqExWjK49Y
            url = url.replace('/watch?v=', '/embed/');
            url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('&'));

            // Fazer append dos vídeos
            $('.videos').append('<iframe width="480" height="270" src="' + url + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        }
    });
});
```

Explicação:

Basicamente o get baixa um feed de vídeos de um canal (alterar onde diz nome_de_utilizador). Depois, é feito um loop que pega no URL de cada vídeo, e aplica uma "correção" que o transforma no URL de embed do Youtube. Por fim, é montado o código HTML do embed, que é adicionado ao div "videos".

O motivo da "correção" de URL é que o Youtube não forneceu uma variável apenas com o ID do vídeo no feed. Teria sido bem conveniente nesse caso.